# Maple plant that will not turn green?

Tags: trees, shrubs, container-gardening, maple, japanese-maple

I live in Ireland. I bought an Acer plant "deshojo" ,few years back . Now I have two issues with this plant. One is that it will give that nice pink/red color only for few months (April -june). The rest of the year its almost green, which i don't like.The second issue for me is that , there is possibility of this plant becoming big for my small garden.So i am going to replace this Acer plant with a new Acer Variety So can someone **help me to find an Acer plant** that's Dwarf (**max 8-9 feet**) and may **not turn to green** (a variety that may convert from **red-pink-red** or **red-orange-yellow**) and will **survive in Ireland** Thanks in Advance

Comment: How large of a Maple would work for you?  Having a tough time understanding having a problem with green.  A tree that changes color during the growing season is a plus.  What do you have going for a landscape where green would be a negative?  There is Acer ginnala...a small multistemmed tree or a large shrub, pruned  to thin for a small tree might fit your bill.  Very very colorful in the fall otherwise, you are looking at beautiful trunks, green canopy great to use to create an outdoor room with walls and a roof...gravel floor?  Green becomes part of the tapestry of your landscape.

Comment: Then there is my favorite tree of all: Amelanchier alnifolia multi trunked...small 'patio' tree with 4 season beauty.  Rare for trees btw.  First to flower in the spring followed by lovely reddish, green smallish rounded leaves.  These leaves change from reddish, purplish to light bright green and then to a dark steady green.  Yummm.  This tree produces berries you can eat IF you are able to harvest them before the birds do.  Black berries.  Dove gray smooth bark.  Gorgeous branching and winter beauty.  Almost no insect or disease.  And would do very well  as a small grove in Ireland...

Comment: I am look for a tree that may grow max to 8-9 feet. I think there are few varieties saying dwarf Maples (caperci dwarf is one of its kind). Color change is good but, if the color change from pink to red or orange or yellow will be better than green as all other pants in my garden are green.

Comment: What the cool thing about green is that it becomes part of a tapestry.  A PROFESSIONAL design will keep most factors; rhythm, color, texture, shape...the same.  Then like fireworks the garden changes through the seasons.  The worst thing people who do not understand art, aesthetics, landscape design rules do is to buy one of everything and nothing at all is similar.  Everything becomes a 'specimen' plant or a 'focal' point. Humans have a hard time with any incoming stimulus that is greater than 3.  If everything is a focal point you will have chaos.  Uncomfortable, unmanageable...

Comment: There is a very big power in mass of one color.  Soothing, understandable, (you won't know why you are uncomfortable in a chaotic setting but I do...grins)...I just gotta know more about what you are trying to achieve.  You do know that I am a Landscape Architect, yes?  Free advice?  Please, send pictures and more information.

Answer (score 3):

The Acer palmatum variety you already have is actually described by the RHS as turning green within a few weeks of the leaves opening, but perhaps you did not find an accurate description prior to purchase. This is not uncommon - Acer palmatum 'Beni-maike' starts out red, turns a glorious pink and then, unfortunately, green within the first 6-8 weeks after leaf break, so if you want one that maintains its colour throughout the growing season, a careful choice has to be made.

There are others which more or less hold their colour until autumn and which don't get so large as the one you currently have, such as Acer palmatum dissectum 'Garnet', or Acer 'Crimson Queen'. Acer 'Bloodgood' holds its colour well, but gets larger than the size you've specified. Info here re Acer 'Garnet', and you can use the search box within the link to check out the other Acer I mentioned - be sure to check the height and spread measurements towards the bottom of the page for each https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/231/i-Acer-palmatum-i-Garnet-(D)/Details. It is much better to choose one that gets the size you want, and not one that gets too large and which you have to constantly prune back - that repeated pruning destroys the line and shape of an Acer palmatum variety, and frequent pruning is not recommended.

Comment: rhs site helped me to find the answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Few I found are given below.

1. Acer palmatum 'Inaba-shidare'
2. Acer palmatum 'Ornatum'
3. Acer palmatum 'Garnet'
4. Acer palmatum 'Dissectum Atropurpureum'
5. Acer palmatum dissectum 'Lace Lady' Tree
6. Acer palmatum dissectum 'Crimson Princess' Tree

and atlast the one i selected is 'skeeters broom'

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid the color of the plant is part of its genetics and might be influenced by seasons.

About your becoming too big problem. *Acers* are ideal for [bonsai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonsai)!

There is also a [purple](https://www.chewvalleytrees.co.uk/products/detail/acer-palmatum-atropurpureum) Japanese Maple (*Acer palmatum atropurpureum*), which you can keep small by pruning. This variety stays red throughout the year, but should be planted in shade/half shade (in full sun the leaves will burn in summer, making them the kind of yellow you don't want).

Comment: Sorry .I think you misunderstand my question.My doubt is to find a new acer plant replacing current one as I have two issues with this. I have edited my question to avoid confusion