# Brilliant red maple tree

Tags: maple

I Just move to the Southern Sweden and I’m looking for a maple tree all year red, especially brilliant red that resists up to -20C.
I have one beni-maiko but it is only brilliant red in early spring and autumn, which is amazing.
However, with a green garden, an all-year red maple would look great! Anyone hás an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: This question and answer might be useful to you https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/38251/maple-plant-that-will-not-turn-green because if you want an Acer that retains its red colour (although its dark red) you need an Acer palmatum variety